# Does the occurrence of an event give any information on it's probability?

Tags: probability

Say you know the outcome of an event. You don't know the probabilities of the event happening or not. Can you infer any information by the occurrence of that event happening?

i.e. You have a deck of 1000 random cards. You pull a dinosaur. Can you insinuate that it's more likely that the deck is half full of dinosaur's than only having 1 dinosaur in the deck?

Comment: You can *insinuate* anything you like!  Whether it's valid to *infer* something about the probabilities will depend on additional assumptions you need to make.  For instance, if you observe a single realization of a Normal random variable (otherwise knowing nothing in advance about the parameters of that distribution), you can still construct a finite confidence interval for the mean.

Answer (score 1):

From sampling only once, you can conclude that the probability of drawing a dinosaur is greater than zero. Any other conclusion would depend on having prior knowledge about the problem.

One example that gets a lot of attention is modeling presidential races. If you only knew who won (a singular sampling), you wouldn't be able to conclude much about the chances the candidates had of winning before the election besides that the winner had a non-zero probability of winning and the loser had a less than one probability of winning.

Edit: for a continuous variable, I would conclude that the probability density function at the value sampled is non-zero.

Comment: You can't even conclude the probability is nonzero if you contemplate sampling from a continuous distribution.